# Android Studio ошибка

Tags: android, android-studio

В примитивном, тестовом приложении студия выдает ошибку. Ошибка на физическом устройстве. В студии следующий текст:

On devices with API level below 21, a full build is required if the app is not running

На всякий случай прикладываю код. Код из main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.user.myapplication.MainActivity">

<Button
android:text="@string/button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:id="@+id/button" />

<TextView
android:text="@string/text"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@+id/button"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="78dp"
android:id="@+id/textView" /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Код из MainActivity.java :

```
package com.example.user.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button button;
TextView text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        text.setText("Нажата кнопка");
    }
});

}
}
```

Comment: Ну так нужно выполнить то что требует студия - "a full build is required".

Comment: Скорее всего надо вырубить `InstantRun` в настройках студии. Видать до 5 версии ОС андроид не умеет в апдейт приложения без полного пересобирания оного.

Comment: А как провести полную сборку ?

Comment: @Cthulhu_Rlyeh, она по умолчанию полная, если отключен `InstantRun`

Comment: Instant Run отключена, все равно прога вылетает. Само приложение запускается но после нажатия на кнопку приложение сворачивается.